# LaTeX not rendering with exact duplicate in review

Tags: bug, mathjax, review

I have come across the following. When reviewing an "Exact duplicate" under the "close votes" the LaTeX doesn't seem to render at all when clicking the supposed duplicate. Is this a bug or is it just my browser?

Comment: It seems not to be your fault. I just noticed the same (Firefox 15 / Ubuntu if that's important, but since it affects only the duplicate displya, I doubt the problem is client side)

Comment: This problem is still there (for me at least) and quite annoying when reviewing. It makes it hard to compare the questions, and requires me to manually open the alleged duplicate question in a new tab to compare them.

Comment: I have the same problem. This bug shouldn't be hard to fixed. Any news on this?